# subclipse broke in sts after I used svn from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

For a long time my subversion client was working just fine, and I used it for a while out of sts, but one day sts crashed and I rolled back to eclipse for a while and during that time I used subclipse to update a project of mine. Now STS is up and running again, but for some reason now if I ever try to update or commit from sts I get the following error:

```
The path '{pathname}' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
```

There is not actually an available update for subclipse and sts still recognizes the most recently installed subclipse from the dashboard. Any ideas on how to fix this one?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to install Subclipse 1.8.x in STS.  The update site URL is:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

That release includes Subversion 1.7 client so you should be all set once you do this.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I already have subclipse installed, which is why this is so baffling.

Comment: Sure, but you obviously have Subclipse 1.6.x installed.  I am telling you how and where to get Subclipse 1.8.x.  You must have other Subversion 1.7 clients on your system like TortoiseSVN.  So you need a version of Subclipse for SVN 1.7 to read that working copy.

Comment: Actually had 1.8 the whole time, again. I am not an idiot. It turns out that using subclipse from eclipse overwrites the classpath that sts uses to something within eclipse that it is really not happy with.

Comment: I never said you were an idiot. The error message that you quote in your question can only come from the Subversion 1.6 API. Subclipse 1.8 will not load the Subversion 1.6 API. So the only way you could get that error is if Subclipse 1.6 is running. Subclipse absolutely does not overwrite anything in Eclipse or STS, I do not think that is even possible.

Comment: no, subclipse doesn't, eclipse overwrote what sts was using. I manually changed the classpath back and it works now, but thank you.

Comment: This is a little late but for those of you just reading this should know that Mark Phippard provided a url above that you enter in the Eclipse after clicking "Install New Software ..." from the "Help" menu. Paste his URL into the "Work with: field and click "Add". You will then be able to upgrade to subclipse 1.8 and the reported issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Subclipse the JavaHL library to do SVN connections.  On Windows, if you have the most recent Subclipse it looks like you should automatically have that installed, but if not they have a variety of installation instructions (alas system dependent).

Comment: I already have the javahl library installed actually, as I am on Windows and have the most recent Subclipse.